# cannot parse json - String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have a problem when trying to parse json from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users, get json response in String and move into JSONArray and then parse it. But,  it says java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray.

my code to get json response is in doInBackground(), parse json in onPostExecute().

Here is my parse code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private RecyclerView rv_user;
    private AdapterUser mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        new AsyncFetch().execute();
    }

    private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String response = "";
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

         }

         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                url = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }

            try {
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {
                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    response = sb.toString();

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    System.out.println(response);

                    return (response);
                } else {
                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
         }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            pdLoading.dismiss();
            List<DataUser> data = new ArrayList<>();
            pdLoading.dismiss();
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                   JSONObject json_user_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                   DataUser userData = new DataUser();
                   userData.id = json_user_data.getString("id");
                   userData.fullName = json_user_data.getString("name");
                   userData.uName = json_user_data.getString("username");
                   userData.email = json_user_data.getString("email");

                   JSONObject addr = json_user_data.getJSONObject("address");
                   String street = addr.getString("street");
                   String city = addr.getString("city");
                   int zip = addr.getInt("zipcode");

                   userData.address = street+", "+ city + " " + zip;
                   userData.phone = json_user_data.getString("phone");
                   userData.web = json_user_data.getString("website");
                   data.add(userData);
                }

                // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
                rv_user = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.userList);
                mAdapter = new AdapterUser(HomeActivity.this, data);
                rv_user.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                rv_user.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(HomeActivity.this));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Help me, please. Thank you.

Comment: Please show where it is failing, and remove unnecessary code

Comment: I am sorry for that. edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change two strings in your code to:

`conn.setDoOutput(false);`
You are going to **read** from server, not write to.

`String zip = addr.getString("zipcode");`
Zip code in your json has form of **59590-4157** and therefore cannot be read as int.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the contents of "result" from the url? I guess it's not what you want.